# Problems with IE7 and Foundation 3 using boxsizing.htc

Tags: internet-explorer-7, zurb-foundation

Using boxsizing.htc is not working for me. The answers to other posts here on Stack Overflow have not worked for me:

[Zerb Foundation 3 - IE7 Fix not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959499/zerb-foundation-3-ie7-fix-not-working)

[Making Zurb's Foundation 3 work with IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788381/making-zurbs-foundation-3-work-with-ie7)

Here's what I did:

1. Created the boxsizing file in TextEdit, put the code there, named it boxsizing.htc, saved as Unicode 8.
2. Uploaded to my javascripts directory, at my domain root.
3. Added this to my stylesheet:

   ```
   * {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     *behavior: url(http://mydomain.com/javascripts/boxsizing.htc); 
   }
   ```
4. Added this to the htaccess file:

   AddType text/x-component .htc
5. To be safe, I made sure that jquery and modernizr are linked before the stylesheet is, just in case the htc file needs jquery.

Still no results. Any ideas?

The site is http://bureauforgood.com/index.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `*behavior: url(/javascripts/boxsizing.htc);`?

I had to fiddle with the path to get this working.